# Unable to start JVM with large heap size on windows

Tags: java, heap-memory

In my Windows 7 64 bit PC, I am trying to start a java application with `-Xmx2048m`.

I need to set a large heap size since the app needs a lot of memory.

My PC has 8GB memory and it has 4GB free when I am trying to start the application.

But, the application fails to start with insufficient memory error.

> Could not reserve enough space for xxxx object heap

Since the PC has more than 2GB free memory, it should be possible to start with max heap size = 2GB.

Why does the application fail to start? Is there any way I can start the app with max heap size = 2GB?

Comment: I do the same thing and it works. Are you sure there is enough unused memory (it should be not just a little more than you specifiy in -Xmx). Furthermore, your java is a 64-bit version? Maybe you should check in the command line that the correct java version is loaded.

Comment: Is installed JRE also x64?

Comment: @JFMeier I was using a 32 bit JRE. When I used a 64 bit JRE, it worked.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Thanks for the support. I was using a 32 bit jre. When I used a 64 bit jre, it worked.